# doClick not releasing keys until loop ends

Tags: java, onclick, click

I'm making a piano application in Java. This is one of the functions,

```
public void playOnce(int time) {
    play();
    doClick(time);
    stop();
}

public void play() {
    channel[0].noteOn(note, 60);
}

public void stop() {
    channel[0].noteOff(note);
}
```

I'll provide a minimal working example if necessary, but I wanted to make sure it's not an obvious issue. The problem is that playOnce is called in a while loop. playOnce is in a Key class, and each Key has a different note. In each iteration of the while loop, playOnce is called on a different key. Once all the keys have been played, it stops.

The doClick method correctly pressed the key, but it's not released until all the keys have been played. In fact, while the keys are being played, you can't do anything, even press the pause button. For this problem, I guess I could put the entire loop in a different thread, but I don't think that type of solution will allow the key to be released.

EDIT: Yea, I figured out I need a new thread to get other actions to work, but I still need a fix for doClick(). This might be more complicated than I thought so here's a working example,

Main.java

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    final int WHITE_KEY_WIDTH, WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT, BLACK_KEY_WIDTH,
            BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT;
    final int WIDTH;
    final JFileChooser fc;
    {
        WHITE_KEY_WIDTH = Key.WHITE_KEY_WIDTH;
        BLACK_KEY_WIDTH = Key.BLACK_KEY_WIDTH;
        WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT = Key.WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT;
        BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT = Key.BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT;
        WIDTH = 3 * (WHITE_KEY_WIDTH * 7) + WHITE_KEY_WIDTH;
        fc = new JFileChooser();
    }

    public static Key keys[] = new Key[48];
    private static int index = 0;
    private String prevText = "";

    JTextArea shabadEditor = null;
    JSpinner tempoControl;
    JFrame frame;
    File curFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        JLayeredPane pianoPanel = new JLayeredPane();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");

        playButton.addActionListener(this);
        playButton.setActionCommand("play");

        pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
        pauseButton.setActionCommand("pause");

        SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 2, .1);
        tempoControl = new JSpinner(model);
        JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) tempoControl
                .getEditor();
        DecimalFormat format = editor.getFormat();
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        Dimension d = tempoControl.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = 40;
        tempoControl.setPreferredSize(d);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        // Construct each top level component
        controlPanel.add(playButton);
        controlPanel.add(pauseButton);
        controlPanel.add(tempoControl);
        shabadEditor = new JTextArea(20, 78);
        constructKeyboard(pianoPanel);

        // Add the piano panel and shabad editor to the window
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        // c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        pianoPanel
                .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH - 18, WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT));
        mainPanel.add(pianoPanel, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        mainPanel.add(shabadEditor, c);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT * 3 + 30);
        frame.setLocation(250, 60);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void constructKeyboard(Container panel) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            addBlackKey(panel, j++);
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            addBlackKey(panel, j++);
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            j++;
            addBlackKey(panel, j++);
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            addBlackKey(panel, j++);
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
            addBlackKey(panel, j++);
            j++;
            addWhiteKey(panel, i++);
        }
    }

    void addWhiteKey(Container panel, int i) {
        WhiteKey b = new WhiteKey();
        b.setLocation(i++ * WHITE_KEY_WIDTH, 0);
        panel.add(b, 0, -1);
        keys[index++] = b;
    }

    void addBlackKey(Container panel, int factor) {
        BlackKey b = new BlackKey();
        b.setLocation(WHITE_KEY_WIDTH - BLACK_KEY_WIDTH / 2 + factor
                * WHITE_KEY_WIDTH, 0);
        panel.add(b, 1, -1);
        keys[index++] = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String action = arg0.getActionCommand();

        if (action.equals("play")) {
            System.out.println("working");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                keys[i].playOnce(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Key.java

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Key extends JButton implements MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT = 200;
    public static final int WHITE_KEY_WIDTH = 40;
    public static final int BLACK_KEY_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT = 120;

    private static int noteCount = 40;
    public int note;

    private static Synthesizer synth = null;

    static {
        try {
            synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            synth.open();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    MidiChannel channel[];

    public Key() {
        note = noteCount++;

        // Instrument[] instruments = synth.getAvailableInstruments();
        // for (Instrument instrument : instruments) {
        // System.out.println(instrument.getName());
        // System.out.println(instrument.getPatch().getBank());
        // System.out.println(instrument.getPatch().getProgram());
        // }

        channel = synth.getChannels();
        channel[0].programChange(20);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void playOnce(int time) {
        play();
        doClick(time);
        stop();
    }

    public void play() {
        channel[0].noteOn(note, 60);
    }

    public void stop() {
        channel[0].noteOff(note);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(this.note);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        play();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        stop();
    }

}
```

BlackKey.java

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class BlackKey extends Key {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BlackKey() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setSize(BLACK_KEY_WIDTH, BLACK_KEY_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

WhiteKey.java

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class WhiteKey extends Key {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WhiteKey() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setSize(WHITE_KEY_WIDTH, WHITE_KEY_HEIGHT);
    }

}
```

EDIT: After doing a bit of work with threading, this is what I have

By putting the for loop in another thread, the keys are released at the right time:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String action = arg0.getActionCommand();

        if (action.equals("play")) {
            System.out.println("working");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        keys[i].playOnce(100);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue now is that the keyboard glitches. The keyboard is created using a layered pane, and for some reason when the keys are released the layers that are supposed to be on the bottom come to the top. When I hover my mouse over them, the glitch goes away. Any ideas?

EDIT2: I fixed the glitches. I simply had to add

```
     try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

after doClick();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are blocking the event thread. This thread is responsible for user input, painting and window updates. My guess is now, that `doClick`'s timeout gets checked inside the event thread (seems logical), so it won't get released until your `actionPerformed` method exits (and so the event thread can continue its event processing).

A solution to this problem would be (as you already mentioned) moving your `for` loop to another thread and call `doClick` using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: If the for loop is in a different thread and doClick is called within that thread, why is it necessary to also call with invokeLater? Everything in the other thread should automatically happen asynchronously, right?

Comment: Java Swing is not thread safe (like most of the GUI frameworks). `invokeLater` is the preferred method for updating Swing components from other threads, it simply makes sure that the `Runnable` you provided to `invokeLater` gets executed in the event thread.

Comment: Can you look at the edit I made at the bottom? I put the loop in a `Runnable`, and even though it works now, the keys are glitchy. Using invokeLater only made the problem worse by not allowing the keys to release.